# My app not showing on Very Large Tablet

Tags: android, google-play

One of the apps I've developed is not showing on [THIS tablet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0167OR4V0). Below is my manifest file. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.app.package">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.Write_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

<application
    android:name="MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   -------

</application>
```

Comment: How do you mean not showing? Can you install it? does it close with an error?

Comment: @washichi I'm not able to find my app on that Tablet in play store. but it is visible on a small tablet of 10" and 7" by searching with same Keywords

Comment: Change the minimal build version in your Gradle to the Android version on your tablet

Comment: min version in gradle file is 17 and Tablet is running 21.

Comment: Please tell the things you tried in your question.. 
Did you read this? https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: some hardware requirement in your permission is causing the device to not allow to install. Use uses feature  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html and set value to false based on your project requirement

Comment: @AmodGokhale Thanks, it worked. Please post this as an answer with a little explanation, so that it can help others in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app you are requesting for permission for hardware requirement. If device doesn't have that hardware capability play store doesn't allow app to install on device.

Use **uses-feature** https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html and set value to false based on your project requirement.

> The purpose of a  declaration is to inform any external
>   entity of the set of hardware and software features on which your
>   application depends. The element offers a required attribute that lets
>   you specify whether your application requires and cannot function
>   without the declared feature, or whether it prefers to have the
>   feature but can function without it. Because feature support can vary
>   across Android devices, the  element serves an important
>   role in letting an application describe the device-variable features
>   that it uses.